# Smart TV (Hisense) microphone connectivity via HDMI

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, microphone, smart-tv

Windows 10 won't recognize microphone. I know the TV has a mic but not a camera. It has a privacy setting for Always Allow and Prompt under Settings > Privacy > Channel Microphone Access.

Neither option seems to get Windows 10 to recognize a microphone and I would like to know if and how it is usable to make voice calls through HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI is uni-directional.
Signal goes from the computer to the TV.

Seems like the HiSense is designed to work with integrated Alexa recognition - https://assets.hisense-canada.com/assets/ProductDownloads/60/177638a62a/Hisense-Alexa-Support-Info-_12.pdf